# Phenyl vs phenol functional group?

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecules

Phenyl is a functional group with an aromatic ring bonded to another group. And, phenol is a molecule that is just a phenyl bonded to a hydroxyl group.

However, [some sources](http://www.harpercollege.edu/tm-ps/chm/100/dgodambe/thedisk/qual/9back7.htm) consider phenol itself a functional group. Are they both functional groups, or is phenol just a molecule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Phenol is both a [molecule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenol) and a [functional group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenols) (or at least a class of molecules). [IUPAC](http://goldbook.iupac.org/P04539.html) has the definitive answer on the matter:

**Phenols:**

> Compounds having one or more hydroxy groups attached to a benzene or other arene ring, e.g. 2-naphthol

Comment: So in addition to a molecule, are phenols only a class of molecules? Or are they also functional groups?

Comment: @epicfaace You can have a phenol moiety, which is a phenyl moiety with at least one hydroxyl group attached. (But I would still consider this kind of nomenclature a little odd.) This way it would/ could be considered a functional group. Going with compound class is more concise however.

Comment: The two links provided never mentioned anything about functional groups. Are classes = functional groups?

Comment: @Cheng Here is the [IUPAC Gold book](https://doi.org/10.1351/goldbook.F02555) definition: Organic compounds are thought of as consisting of a relatively unreactive backbone, for example a chain of sp3 hybridized carbon atoms, and one or several functional groups. The functional group is an atom, or a group of atoms that has similar chemical properties whenever it occurs in different compounds. It defines the characteristic physical and chemical properties of families of organic compounds.